# How do I properly return 'this' in Thenable objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing a NodeJS package that contains a Thenable class (see [Thenable objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#thenable_objects)) that is supposed to return `this` (the initialized object itself), but instead it is returning a new, uninitialized object and it is stuck in a neverending loop. Below is the code:

*node_modules/<my package>/index.js*

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const config = require('./config.json');

class MyAPI {

  #token = "";

  constructor(username, password) {
    this.#token = token;
  }

  then(resolve, reject) {
    const options = {
      url: "/api/authenticate",
      baseURL: "https://myapi.com/",
      method: 'post',
      maxRedirects: 0,
      data: {
        token: this.#token
      },
      transformRequest: this.#transformRequest('urlencoded'),
      transformResponse: this.#transformResponse
    };
    axios.request(options).then((res) => {
      if (res.data.authenticated === true) {
        console.log("Authenticated!");
        resolve(this); // <-- should return the initialized object, but instead returns a new uninitialized object
      } else {
        reject(new Error('Invalid credentials'));
      }
    });
  }

  #transformRequest(type) {
    if (type === 'urlencoded') {
      return function(data) {
        return (new URLSearchParams(data)).toString();
      }
    } else if (type === 'json') {
      return function(data) {
        return JSON.stringify(data);
      }
    }
  }

  #transformResponse(data) {
    return JSON.parse(data);
  }

  getSomething() {
    // Gets something from remote API
    return response;
  }

}

module.exports.MyAPI = MyAPI;
```

*index.js*

```js
const { MyAPI } = require('<my package>');
(async function(){
  try {
    const app = await new MyAPI(config.auth.token);
    console.log("App initialized!"); // Code never reaches this command
    console.log(app.getSomething());
  } catch (e) {...} // Handle the error
})()
```

The log gets filled up with "Authenticated!" and the code never makes it to `console.log("App initialized!")`. I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485) but it does not help me because I know `this` is referring correctly to the object.

Replacing `resolve(this)` with `resolve()` stops this, but `await new MyAPI()` resolves to `undefined` and I cannot later run `app.getSomething()`.

In a non-Thenable class (e.g. `new MyClass()`), it resolves to the object itself, so further operations can be done on it, so why can't `await new MyAPI()` also resolve to the object itself like a constructor should?

Comment: "*a thenable that is supposed to [resolve with] `this`*" - not sure why you would want that. Is your actual goal to make the `const app = await new MyAPI(config.auth.token);` syntax work? If so, I suggest to have a look at [Is it bad practice to have a constructor function return a Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi `new MyAPI()` resolves to the object itself, so further operations can be done on it, so why can't `await new MyAPI()` resolve to the object itself like a constructor should?

Comment: @Maytha8 `new MyAPI()` returns a thenable. When you `await` it, it's calling the `.then()`. Which returns the same instance. Which is a thenable. When you `await` it, it's calling the `.then()`. Which returns the same instance. Which is a thenable. When you `await` it, it's calling the `.then()`. Which returns the same instance. Which is a thenable. Can you see where the problem is?

Comment: I meant that if `MyAPI` wasn't a thenable. I'll rephrase. `class MyAPI { constructor(token) {this.#token = token;} doSomething() {...}}`. `const app = new MyAPI(token)` resolves to a class. `app.doSomething()` does something and does not throw an error. Now let's go back to the thenable. `const app = await new MyAPI(token);` keeps looping. You can't then do `app.getSomething()`. If I changed `resolve(this)` to `resolve()`, then `app === undefined //true` and you still can't do `app.getSomething()`. Can you see where the problem is?

Comment: I already said what you said in my question, and I can see the problem. That's why this question exists in the first place @VLAZ. The title says 'How do I **properly return 'this'** in Thenable objects?'

Comment: Again, the problem is that you resolve the `.then()` with a thenable. With an `await` that thenable also has to be resolved until a plain *non-thenable* value. But since it always resolves to a thenable, it has to be resolved infinitely. Your question here is asking the wrong thing, because the proper thing isn't to try and jury-rig a `.then()` to do some instantiation logic and return the same instance. Hence why Bergi's answer doesn't do that. And seems you accepted it - I don't think you should go back to asking about writing weird unconventional code that requires hacks to even work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't do that. Instead of making your objects thenable, give them an `init` method that simply returns a promise. Then use them as

```
const app = new MyAPI(config.auth.token);
await app.init();
console.log("App initialized!");
```

Comment: For sure a better practice. Why not a factory though? Seems like that would be less error prone than 2 phase construction.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I do definitely recommend a factory (e.g. a static method on the class), but this was the smallest change to their current code and I'm not entirely certain what their actual goal was. With an `init` method, you can potentially initialise the same instance twice (e.g. if the first authentication attempt failed).

Comment: Is it better to return a `new Promise`, or to make the function `async` and `await` the axios request?

Comment: @Maytha8 Don't use `new Promise`, `axios` already returns one. You can either `await` it or `return axios(…).then(…);`.

Comment: I moved the authentication from the constructor to a new method, `static authenticate(token)`.